# Video streaming in web service c#

Tags: c#, web-services, video-streaming

Here is my code for web service i made:

```
 public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<UploadFile> GetUploadedFiles()
    {
        using (Database1Entities1 SampleDb = new Database1Entities1())
        {
            return SampleDb.UploadFiles.ToList();
        }
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public void ViewData(int File_ID)
    {
        using (Database1Entities1 SampleDb = new Database1Entities1())
        {
            var File = SampleDb.UploadFiles.Where(f => f.Id.Equals(File_ID)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (File != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = File.ContentType;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + File.Name);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(File.Content);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }
        }
     }
     }
      }
```

This service returns the dataset containing videos when i stream them at separate webform instead of calling it through client it works properly but when i call it through client service it does not stream videos. any one??

Comment: You need to set `Content-Length` and handle `Range` requests.

Comment: how it will help me?? and where i am going to set these parameters?? client or service?